# Error in JSON list deserialize

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson, pojo

I'm developing a GWT web application with a RESTful web service. The web service's results are deserializing to POJO with Jackson 1.8. It's work fine with simple fields. However, it fails when it try to deserialize a list of POJO. This is the POJO with list to deserialize:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DatosIndicadoresSVclaveDTO implements Serializable {
    ...
    @XmlAttribute
    @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = IdeologicoVOXDTO.class)
    public List<IdeologicoVOXDTO> ideologicoVox;
    ...

    //getter/setters
}
```

And this is the POJO that contains the list

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IdeologicoVOXDTO implements Serializable {
    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer numeroPalabra;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String palabra;
    @XmlAttribute
    private Integer categoria;
    ...

    //getter/setters
}
```

The JSON have this structure:

```
{datosIndicadoresSVclave: {
        ...
        "ideologicoVox":[
            {
                "categoria":"1", 
                "numeroPalabra":"1", 
                "palabra":"abandonado", 
                ...
            },
            {
                "categoria":"2", 
                "numeroPalabra":"3", 
                "palabra":"hambre", 
                ...
            }
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

When it's running, the web service's results works fine, but the deserialize print this error:

SEVERE: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@10b61ad; line: 1, column: 580] (through reference chain: org.ull.etsii.client.dto.DatosIndicadoresSVclaveDTO["ideologicoVox"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)

Any idea?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved!!

The problem is the size list is variable, and it fails if it has one element. The Jackson's version is 1.7, that it can't accept arrays single value. My solution is GSON with a custom register type, and I've used the Joshi's adviced. It works great!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced some similar kind of problem and tried the following way, and it worked for me.

Create a new class which contains property 
~ public List ideologicoVox ~

And use this class reference as property to the main class i.e ~ DatosIndicadoresSVclaveDTO

Comment: I've created the new class with property List<IdeologicoVOXDTO> listaIdeologicoVox, and I've included this refference in DatosIndicadoresSVclaveDTO, but not worked: SEVERE: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of org.ull.etsii.client.dto.ListaIdeologicoVOXDTO out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@10dcfdd; line: 1, column: 583] (through reference chain: org.ull.etsii.client.dto.DatosIndicadoresSVclaveDTO["ideologicoVox"])